# What determines the capacity of a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning

For a KNN model, is the value of K inversely proportional to its capacity/complexity? How can one determine whether a curve is a training curve or a validation curve based on its Loss Vs Capacity graph? Thanks! ML newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K in KNN is a hyperparameter that determines how many (K) votes from the 'nearest neighbors' are supposed to be considered to make a prediction against a sample. What do you mean by the capacity of the model? Also, the larger K is, the more complex the model.

Comment: Thanks! From what I can find out on the internet, the capacity of a model is used interchangeably with the complexity.

Comment: Superb! I'm glad you got your answer.